# MySQL SUM returns wrong value

Tags: mysql, sum

If I add a table like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and add an entry:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`value`) VALUES ('123.45');
```

and do a SUM on it like this:

```
SELECT SUM( value )
FROM `test`
```

why does it return 123.449996948242 and not 123.45?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of floating point inaccuracy. Use [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) data type instead.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

See this example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdb40/1)

Answer (score 0):

Because a floating point number has some precision "problems" about:

1. precision of your machine (limited number of digit that you can store)
2. representation error
3. so on...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SELECT 
      ROUND( SUM(value), 2)
FROM `test`
```